# Display large content within fixed height of webview in android

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, webview

i am having a large HTML page ,displaying it in web-view android and i want whenever user will click the "fill height" it will fit the large HTML page completely within web-view height without any vertical scroll-bar i.e complete webpage will be shown in web-view height(that can vary device to device) ,Any solution??

Thanks In Advanced,please help me??

==>please give your suggestions to fixed this issue.

Comment: are you using a scrol view in the same layout?

Comment: @droidhot NO,i am having a web-view with params fill_parent inside a relative layout with same params

Comment: @krish its ok,just use your sense that what he is trying to say,guys please provide me some solutions

Comment: put a scroll view (and use wrap content) or specify a height for the web view scroll bars should come then - i hope so

Comment: @droidhot but whenever i will click button "fill height" i donot want any vertical scrollbar and the large page should displayed in webview completely

Comment: even a single useful response i didn't get

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)` and  `mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)` and see if that solves the problem. I'm setting this in my `onCreate` and when a page is loaded it completely fills the whole webview

Comment: I'm not sure that it will work when you press the button since I've been using it when configuring the webview, maybe you have to reload the page or something

Comment: aah, sry, missed that part of your question

Comment: its OK,just see what you can do for mine problem

Comment: I'm looking into the issue, but why accept the answer if it's not fully satisfying your needs?

Comment: please don't accept answers it if not rectify the issue. Because lot of people thinks the accepted one is the solutions. if you accept the answer the status of the answer is closed and most of the people will not see ur question in future to provide a solution.